# How to lock a character in an input field

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an input text field in Flash and I want to keep a dollar sign at all times in front of it.
Normally I would just left align the input field and have a "$" next to it so it's uneditable, but in this instance the text field has to be center aligned.

I thought to just include a function to add "$" in front of all the text every time the field loses focus - but realised that would be a problem if there was already a $ sign in front and it just kept adding them.

Also - once I've done this, is there a way to grab the value from that input field excluding the "$"? Eg: some sort of splice that splices the first character and just grabs the rest of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the $:

```
tf.addEventListener( Event.CHANGE, onTextChange );

function onTextChange( e:Event ):void
{
   if ( tf.text.charAt(0) != "$" )
    tf.text = "$" + tf.text;
}
```

And to get the text without the first character:

```
var yourText :String = tf.text.substring(1, tf.text.length);
```

Comment: Thanks Sanchez, I didn't think to check for "$" before adding it! And I didn't know Event.CHANGE existed.

Perfect! Thanks a bunch you've saved me a lot of time.